# Remove a vector from a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Suppose I have a $N \times N$ matrix $A$ which is a projection matrix on the column space of another matrix $B=[b_1, \ldots, b_n], n<N $, that is, $A=BB^\dagger$, with $^\dagger$ denoting the pseudoinverse. Clearly every vector $b_i$ belongs to the column space of $B$ and as such $A b_i= b_i$.

I want to modify matrix $A$ in such a way that $b_j$, for a specific fixed $j$, does not belong anymore to the subspace spanned by $A$. So I would like $A b_j \neq b_j$. How to achieve it?

Comment: I corrected my question

Comment: Could you clarify?   A matrix doesn't span a space. While I guess I might "get it", the wording of the second paragraph is off.  How about replacing the $j$th column of $B$ by the zero vector?

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. You would like $Ab_j\ne b_j,$ and probably even $b_j\notin\operatorname{range}(A),$ but which properties of $A$ do you want to maintain? Do you want $A$ to be a projection matrix? do you want its range to be the span of all other $b_i$'s?

Comment: To answer to both of you: you are right, I should say that the vector does not belong anymore to the subspace spanned by the columns of $A$. I still would like to have $A$ as a projection matrix with its range to the the span of all the other vectors $b_i$.